# Android login form

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a site created with cakephp that contains a UsersController and action login & signin works well

```
function signup(){
        //tester si il ya des donnéer a poster:
        if($this->request->is('post')){
            $d = $this->request->data;
            $d['User']['id'] = null;
            if(!empty($d['User']['password'])){
                      //encrypt the password   :           
           $d['User']['password'] = Security::hash($d['User']['password'],null,true);

            }
```

and I created a simple android application that allows you to connect a user who is already register through the website, 
but I did not understand how to test the existence login and password using cakephp or another php file
any solution please ?
I use cakephp 2.0.0-RC2 version

Comment: You question is not clear

Comment: @user574632 : for example, this password 6a3a36c59e60b9b4bc11dae7f9251e769e0ce853  
generated by cakephp in my database and I want to decrypted with android for test the validate login and password with another php file or cakephp if this possible

Comment: You cant decrypt a hash, its a one way thing. I think there is still some misunderstanding here

Comment: @user574632 : this method "$this->Auth->login()" return true if user is exists but it's used in cakephp, so how to do it in php

Answer (score 0):

http://www.androidsnippets.com/executing-a-http-post-request-with-httpclient can help you to do a POST request to your php. Your name value pairs will be User-value and password-value. You can create a simple form layout with 2 edit text and a button and set the values there.

Comment: But your php and your client needs some work to do. After you get the User and password in the server, you need to check if the user exists in your database or wherever you store your users, and check if the password is a match. Then you can echo a page contains either xml, soap or json or which ever markup language you want to use. Like <result>SUCCESS</result><info></info> (simple xml). Then in the client, you get the result, parse it and check if your result value equals SUCCESS which means you successfully login.